# FCKEditor disappeared in codeigniter after i removed index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, fckeditor

I have Used FCKEditor in some modules of my project ,at that time i was using `index.php` in my url,but when i removed `index.php`, FCKEditor disappeared from page,its not showing any error just FCKEditor's place shows blank
Any idea???

```
$fckeditorConfig = array('instanceName' => 'fckcontent',
                         'BasePath' => base_url().'systemfiles/plugins/FCKeditor/', 
                         'ToolbarSet' => '', 
                         'Width' => '600', 
                         'Height' => '370',
                         'Value' => $this->input->post('fckcontent'));

$this->load->library('fckeditor', $fckeditorConfig);
```

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst It was an older version of CKEditor. FCKeditor was named after the programmer who created(brazillian as far as i remember). Later he changed it to CKEditor . Nishant use CKEditor. not necessarily solves your problem but fckeditor is outated.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst..I think that might not be issue coz it was working before 2 days,but i removed index.php from url by editing config.php and its stop working now

Comment: The asset files for the editor, like the JS, CSS and image files, maybe partially or wholly in a path now being intercepted by your autoloadeder/front controller. What steps have you take to understand the problem so far?

Comment: Thanks but for the help...now it is solved problem with my .hracess content

Comment: My apologies, I ddn't understand. You figured out it was your `.htaccess` file that's the problem?` If yes, can you include it in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: make .htaccess

```
#RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

User guide:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Second step: edit config\config.php and set base_url()

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

and remove index page

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Third step: don't use fckeditor, use ckeditor

Read wiki:
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CKEditor